# Can I use Poisoner's Gloves to make a touch attack on myself during a Full Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, touch-attacks

I'm a Warpriest with an Alchemist in the party. Being able to let the Alchemist give me an Enlarge Person infusion without eating up his action would be pretty neat.

Is it legal for me to make a Full Attack with several iteratives, and make on of those attacks a Touch Attack against myself to deliver a potion/Infusion from [these gloves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-poisoner-s)?

As I understand, Touch Attacks are just an Attack like any other.
I know that I must start with my highest bonus first, so if I have +7/+2, I'd have to choose between buffing myself with the gloves before making an attack at +2, or making an attack at +7 first and getting the buff after that.

The Poisoner's Gloves specifically allow me to deliver the contents as part of a touch attack (or an unarmed strike/Natural weapon attack, but I don't intend to clock myself).

My question is, can I make a touch attack against myself as part of a Full Attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are no rules addressing this explicitly, but I see no reason this shouldn’t work.

1. Touch attacks are attacks like any other. You can definitely use one as one of your attacks in a full-attack.
2. You can definitely touch yourself.

So without something explicitly covering this combo, it seems like it should work.